# custom metadata in Stripe checkout session for payment_intent.payment_failed event Python

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments, webhooks, payment-gateway

I want to get user id in **payment_intent.payment_failed** event and client_refrence_id isn't in request data in payment_failed event from stripe. I tried **metadata={'user_id': user_id}** but this too isn't showing in request data. Also tried this **subscription_data.metadata = {"metadata": {"bar": "BAR", }},** but it is showing syntax error **"SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?** and even if I do this (==) it says **SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument**
Here is my code:

```
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                client_reference_id=user_id,
                # metadata={'user_id': user_id},
                subscription_data.metadata = {"metadata": {"bar": "BAR", }},
                success_url="success_url",
                cancel_url="cancel_url",
                payment_method_types=["card"],
                mode="subscription",
                line_items=[
                    {
                        "price": price_id,
                        "quantity": 1,
                    }
                ],
            )
```

Here's my webhook code

```
def webhook_received(self):
        payload = request.data
        endpoint_secret = 'my_secret_key'
        sig_header = request.headers.get('stripe-signature')

        try:
            event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
                payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
            )
            data = event['data']
        except:
            pass
        event_type = event['type']
        if event_type == 'checkout.session.completed':
            self.handle_checkout_session(data)
        elif event_type == 'payment_intent.payment_failed':
            self.saving_failed_subscription_data(data)
        return "success"
```

Comment: Okay so first let's clarify a few things so it will be easier to help you out


1. Are you looking for the customer ID from Stripe (e.g. cus_XXXXX)?

2. You cannot pass metadata to the subscription object from the Checkout session object.

3. Can you share your webhook handling code?

Comment: No, I want the users id from my db table(which I have as current_user.id but in webhook I can't access the current user). I want to send it in metadata somehow so I can associate the webhook event with a user. Also updated question with webhook code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pass the metadata through to the subscription in when creating the checkout session *in Python*, you need to use nested dictionaries instead of dot notation.  So in your case you would revise the creation of the checkout session like so:

```py
checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                client_reference_id=user_id,
                # metadata={'user_id': user_id},
                # subscription_data.metadata = {"metadata": {"bar": "BAR", }}, <-- won't work
                # This should work to get data to invoice/subscription
                 subscription_data = {
                  "metadata": {"user_id": user_id}
                 },
              # This will get the metadata on to the related payment_intent
                payment_intent_data={
                  "metadata": {"user_id": user_id}
                },
                success_url="success_url",
                cancel_url="cancel_url",
                payment_method_types=["card"],
                mode="subscription",
                line_items=[
                    {
                        "price": price_id,
                        "quantity": 1,
                    }
                ],
            )
```

This approach of using dictionaries is required in Python to post data for any of the nested attributes that the Stripe APIs allow you to manipulate.

The [`Create a Session` docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create) have a pretty long list of configurable parameters that it is worth reviewing, now that you've got the syntax for how to append nested data.

Comment: Now, I can see metadata in invoice.payment_failed event but in payment_intent.payment_failed event metadata is still empty. I really want to save data when payment_intent.payment_failed called as it has message and reason of failure in request data.

Comment: Updated the answer to include the payment_intent_data parameter in the checkout session